# Ruby on Rails: How to sort a collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sorting

I want to sort / order it (desc or asc how i want it) by the database table column "plays"
Im totally confused. Just found a solution for select but not collection_select?

some code of my view

```
<%= f.collection_select :player1, Player.all, :id, :name %>
```

dont know how to sort / order

there are also columns in the database table like "plays", "goals" ...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just pass actually ordered collection to collection_select helper:

```
collection_select(:post, :author_id, Author.order('created_at DESC'), :id, :name_with_initial, :prompt => true)
```

So, in your source example it will look like this:

```
<%= f.collection_select :player1, Player.order('plays DESC'), :id, :name %>
```

Comment: dont know what you mean, am a newbie. could you change the code to my view so it will work and where to add this code by you? tried Player.all.order('created_at DESC') in the view but didnt work?

Comment: This is the right idea, but calling `all` executes the SQL query (which is why you can't call `order` afterward).  You can simply move `.all` to the end of the chain or remove it completely since it is implied.  `<%= f.collection_select :player1, Player.order('plays DESC'), :id, :name %>`